# Will there be any anti-cheating measures that affect the broadcast in the Candidates tournament?

Tags: cheating, candidates

In the current Women World Championship the games are transmitted with a delay to avoid cheating. Searching if something similar will happen for the Candidates tournament I could just found the [information](https://www.chess.com/news/candidates-to-start-friday-agon-blocks-games-transmission-by-chess-sites-5161) that the games will be only be available in the official webpage.

Is it going to be any delay or any other anti-cheating measure that affects the broadcasting of the games applied in the Candidates?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it going to be any delay or any other anti-cheating measure that
>   affects the broadcasting of the games applied in the Candidates?

It is mostly Agon protecting their commercial rights to the event.

They forbid rebroadcasting and require users / viewers to login and click agreement to a complicated piece of lawyer-speak which is unintelligible to normal people.

Being cynical I expect any delay for other organizations covering the event will come from one of their members subscribing and then playing the moves on a chessboard in front of him so somebody else can broadcast them.

There is no copyright on chess moves or games, only on commentary.

Comment: Thanks. For those concerned with privacy I want to add that you can login in the official webpage using a disposable email address.